# How do I extract and store a portion of the string and store it in an array?

Tags: vb.net

I have a file array which carries strings in the following format:

"abc12345.xxx_xxx001.001045"

The string stored in above format helps me do a portion of my job

Now, having stored this, I want to extract a portion of this string and store it an array

How do I extract "abc12345" alone from this string and store it an array?

I tried using the split command. The problem am facing is:
 PN(0) stores abc12345
 PN(1) stores xxx_xx001
 PN(2) stores 001045
 I want abc12345 to be stored as PN(0) and next subsequent part number to be stored as PN(1)

Copy Code

```
Dim PN As New ArrayList()
For Each element In file1array
    PN = element.split("."c)
Next
```

Comment: What about those that dont have a prefix?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every element contains a period and the first segment is the part number,

```
pn = file1Array.Select(
    function(element as string)
        return element.Split("."c)(0)
    end function
    ).ToArray()
```

This would return `pn` as an array of `string`, not an `ArrayList`.

It's saying, for each `element` in `file1Array`, split `element` into an array and return the first element in that array (the part number.)

Then take all of those values and put them in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring and indexOf:

```
Dim list As New ArrayList()
For Each Str As String In file1array
    list.Add(Str.Substring(0, Str.IndexOf(".")))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the split function like you are doing and just concatenate index 1 and 2 to make the result you want?

```
Dim PN As New ArrayList()
For Each element In file1array
    PN = element.split("."c)
    PN(1) = PN(1) & PN(2)
Next
```